# Order of execution in Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I have a parent and a child component below is the code:

**Parent component HTML:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-tabset>
        <lightning-tab label="Child One">
            <c-child-one record-id={sobjectId}></c-child-one>
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Child Two">
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Child Three">
        </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

**Parent Component JS:**

```
import {LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import getRecordId from '@salesforce/apex/DemoCTRL.getRecordId'

export default class ChildOne extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    sobjectId;

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('Constructor Called in Parent');
    }

    //getting dependent record Id
    @wire(getRecordId, {recordId: '$recordId'}) getSobjectId({error, data}) { 
        if(data) {
            console.log('Wired Called In Parent');
            this.sobjectId= data;
        }
        else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

**Child Component HTML:**

```
<template>
    <table class="sobject-table slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <template for:each={fieldSetData} for:item="field">
                    <th key={field.apiName} title={field.fieldLabel} class="" data-scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title={field.fieldLabel}>{field.fieldLabel}</div>
                    </th>
                </template>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template for:each={records} for:item="row">
                <tr key={row} class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <template for:each={row} for:item="data">
                        <td key={data.id} data-label="Name" data-scope="row">{data.value}</td>
                    </template>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

**Child Component JS:**

```
import {LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import {processRecords} from 'c/recordGenerator';
import getFieldSetData from '@salesforce/apex/FieldSetData.getFieldSetData';
import getSobjectRecords from '@salesforce/apex/DeomoCTRL.getRecords';
import VanillaDatatable from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/VanillaDatatable';
import {loadScript, loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class ManageSelectedIndicators extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    records;
    fieldSetData;
    @wire(
        getFieldSetData,
        {objectName: 'SOBJECTName', fieldSet: 'FIELSETName'}
    ) wiredFieldSetData({error, data}) {
        console.log('wired called in Child')
        if (data) {
            this.fieldSetData = data;
            this.getData();
        }
    }


    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('Constructor called in Child');
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('Connected callback');
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log('Rendered callback');
        // Promise.all([
        //     loadScript(this, VanillaDatatable + '/VanillaDataTables/src/vanilla-dataTables.js')
        // ]).then(() => {
        //     const table = new DataTable(
        //         document.getElementsByClassName('.project-indicator'),
        //         {searchable: true, sortable : true}
        //     );
        // })
        // .catch(error => {
        //    console.log(error);
        // });
    }

    getData() {
        getSobjectRecords ({
            sobjectId: this.recordId
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.records= processRecords(response, this.fieldSetData);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

}
```

Here's the result after the page has loaded:

[image]

I'm not sure what's going on here and as a result of that my table is not rendering with data (only table headers are rendered because fieldSetData is populated) and I'm unable to instantiate the `new DataTable()` JS because the table doesn't exist.

**Edit:** looks like the `sobjectId` only gets populated after the child has rendered and hence the `records` is empty.

Please recommend the best approach to get the record in the parent -> pass it to the child component -> load related records -> render the table -> then call the JS

Comment: You would typically ensure that values used in your template are reactive; if you make "records" tracked I suspect things will render correctly.

Comment: @PhilW I have tried that but the behaviour is very inconsistent. Is there anything else that I'm doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Since in the order of execution for child cmp, wired is fired before connecttedCallback is called, have you tried calling getData() in connectedCallback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@wire(
    getFieldSetData,
    {objectName: 'SOBJECTName', fieldSet: 'FIELSETName'}
)
```

This wire in child is getting called even before you get recordId from parent and so you cannot say when will `getSobjectRecords` be invoked and when its response is returned, whether or not fieldSet information is available or not.

### fixes:

Option 1. Render child only when `sobjectId` is available: (preferred)

```
    <c-child-one if:true={sobjectId} record-id={sobjectId}></c-child-one>
```

Option 2.

```
    @wire(
        getFieldSetData,
        {objectName: 'SOBJECTName', fieldSet: 'FIELSETName', recordId: '$recordId'}
    )
```

Make above wire dependent on recordId. This will get data only if it gets valid `recordId`

#### Added based on comments:

`if:true` is like normal javascript ***if*** condition which checks if value is:

1. not null
2. not undefined
3. not blank
4. is true if boolean

Comment: Will `if:true={sobjectId}` work as in the code example above right now? Or do we you need a `doesSObjectIdExist` getter method in the JS code?

Comment: @BrianMiller added in answer

Comment: Fantastic - I didn't know the `if:true` worked like a regular JS condition check

Comment: I believe is:true will also return false if it's an empty array

Comment: @MayTheSForceBeWithYou as its just like regular JS function, what you said is correct - `[]` and `{}` are not really empty/null/undefined. and so it returns false